# ORDER values by the Highest match in IN Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    talb1                          tabl2
[id   -   col1]               [tid   -   col1]
[1    -    aa1]               [1     -      c]
[2    -    ba2]               [1     -      b]
[3    -    ca3]               [1     -      a]
[4    -    da4]               [1     -      d]
                              [2     -      c]
                              [2     -      a]
                              [2     -      b]
                              [3     -      b]
                              [3     -      a]
                              [4     -      a]
```

in the following query

```
$query = "
SELECT a.id 
FROM a.tabl1 
LEFT JOIN tabl2 b ON a.id = b.tid 
WHERE b.col1 IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
GROUP BY a.id
";
```

I'm trying to get the highest `ID`s matched within the `IN Clause`, I get the values, But they're never ordered,

I want to order them by the highest id having the highest match

for example

```
ID[4] = match['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
ID[2] = match['a', 'b', 'c'];
ID[3] = match['a', 'b'];
ID[1] = match['a'];
```

so i tried

`ORDER BY COUNT(b.col1) DESC` but it is clearly won't do anything as i want it to happen, How exactly to order a query like this?

Note: If i've selected `a, b, c` only inside the `IN Clause` i get ordered values, But if selected `a, b, c, d` (All letters) i get random values.

Comment: This `ORDER BY COUNT(b.col1) DESC` should do similar to your criteria, I don't get it how its not, Its better if you can include some sample data

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Added a sample table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GROUP BY` in order to use`ORDER BY COUNT(...)`:

```
SELECT a.id , COUNT(b.col1) AS cnt
FROM tabl1 a
LEFT JOIN tabl2 b 
  ON a.id = b.tid 
 AND b.col1 IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/TAZYFS85554)**

Comment: Yes, I had the `GROUP BY` added it now, The query tiself works correctly sometimes, But if i have selected all the `a, b, c, d` inside the IN query, it starts being random. If `IN` has `a, b, c` it works as intended, but `a,b,c,d` is totally false.

Comment: @AXAI Please check now

Comment: I thought about this solution, But is it the only possible solution for an accurate ORDER?